# How copy data from one sheet to another by mapping Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets. Sheet 1 is Mapping of column and Sheet 2 is Data.
    I wants to copy data from sheet 2 to new sheet 3 by using Sheet 1.
    sheet 1,Sheet 2 is shown below

[image: Sheet1 :Column mapping]
[image: Sheet 2: Data with File name and sheet name]
[image: Sheet 3 : Output Expecting]

Code:

```
Sub ModdedMap()

    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet, Sh3 As Worksheet
    Dim HeadersOne As Range, HeadersTwo As Range
    Dim hCell As Range


    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Sh1 = .Sheets("Sheet 1") 'Modify as necessary.
        Set Sh2 = .Sheets("Sheet 2") 'Modify as necessary.
       Set Sh3 = .Sheets("Sheet3") 'Modify as necessary.
    End With

    Set HeadersOne = Sh3.Range("P2:P" & Sh3.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each hCell In HeadersOne

        SCol = GetColMatched(Sh1, hCell.Value)
        TCol = GetColMatched(Sh2, hCell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        LRow = GetLastRowMatched(Sh1, hCell.Value)

        For Iter = 2 To LRow
            Sh2.Cells(Iter, TCol).Value = Sh1.Cells(Iter, SCol).Value
        Next Iter

    Next hCell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate

End Sub

Function GetLastRowMatched(Sh As Worksheet, Header As String) As Long
    ColIndex = Application.Match(Header, Sh.Rows(1), 0)
' On Error Resume Next
    GetLastRowMatched = Sh.Cells(Rows.Count, ColIndex).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Function GetColMatched(Sh As Worksheet, Header As String) As Long
    ColIndex = Application.Match(Header, Sh.Rows(1), 0)
    'On Error Resume Next
    GetColMatched = ColIndex
    ' On Error Resume Next
End Function
```

Comment: This line is very confusing ` Set HeadersOne = Sh3.Range("P2:P" & Sh3.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)` .  You need to remove `.Row`.  It's unclear what you actually want to do. Do you want to copy a range on Sheet2 to Sheet3 then change it's header row?

Comment: i wants to copy sheet 2 data as it is into sheet 3. But header name (column name ) must be "MyColumn" name from sheet 1. Sheet 1 contains column mapping.

Comment: the i have written is not working ....i am not getting where i went wrong

Comment: The only cells that your code changes are in the header row of sheet 2. What is the first cell with information on Sheet2 'Range("A1")`?  What is the destination range on Sheet3 'Range("A1")`?

Comment: yes its Range"A1" but the sheet 2 contains some of the column names only not all. Just i wants to change header to column names from Sheet 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Function getAlteranteHeaderName(value As String)` will lookup the new header value.  `Sub CopyDataRemapHeader()` is a minimalistic example of how you can copy a range from `Sheet 2` to `Sheet3` and then if an alternate header row name exists change it.

```
Sub CopyDataRemapHeader()
    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet, Sh3 As Worksheet
    Dim HeadersRow As Range, hCell As Range
    Dim newName As String

    Set Sh1 = Sheets("Sheet 1")
    Set Sh2 = Sheets("Sheet 2")
    Set Sh3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

    With Sh3
        Sh2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy .Range("A1")
        Set HeadersRow = Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        For Each hCell In HeadersRow
            newName = getAlteranteHeaderName(hCell.Text)
            If Len(newName) Then hCell.value = newName
        Next hCell

    End With


End Sub

Function getAlteranteHeaderName(value As String) As String
    Dim rOld As Range, rNew As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
        Set rNew = Intersect(.Range("A:A"), .UsedRange)
        Set rOld = Intersect(.Range("B:B"), .UsedRange)
        On Error Resume Next
        getAlteranteHeaderName = WorksheetFunction.Index(rNew, WorksheetFunction.Match(value, rOld, 0))
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Function
```

Here is a screenshot of the output.

[image]

Here is my [Test Stub](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tzild5flaaf94sy/amar-6477683.xlsm?dl=0) if you would like to download it.

Comment: i am getting output same as sheet 2 but i want to change headers to "MyColumn " column names  e.g. in sheet 2 i have email   pin banknme faxno  a/c no change this to Name     PIN    Bank Name    Fax No    Account No

Comment: I was quite through when creating the test stub.  My out put is correct.  I renamed the sheets to match the names in your code.  In your code Sheet1 is names **Sheet 1** if this isn't correct the code will not rename the headers.